# Upgrading Migrations for Devise 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[This guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0) for upgrading Devise to 2.0 mentions [upgrading migrations](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style).

Is that really necessary even if the schema is all how it should be?

I don't understand how you could just tack on a new migration for a table that already exists and is up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think they mean for you to add new migrations. It doesn't have anything to do with changing your table structure. I think they are saying that you will need to update your *original* migration file(s). Since they removed the old migration helpers like `t.rememberable`, you will not be able to re-run your old migrations until you replace things like `t.rememberable` with `t.datetime :remember_created_at`.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't sure if it was a faux pas to edit one of those datestamped migration files. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't make a change that causes the migration to produce a different result, but refactoring / changing the syntax is probably just fine.